# Select query, join the collection field with other table number field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

TABLE: stores

```
----------------------------------------------
store_cd    store_nm    active    material_cat_ids
---------------------------------------------
L           Store(L)    Y         20,5
B           Store(B)    Y         7
```

And
Table : Material_category

```
----------------------------------------------------------
material_cat_id    name                        active
----------------------------------------------------------
20                 Material Category type A    Y
5                  Material Category type B    Y
7                  Material Category type C    Y
```

Now I need join between both tables (`stores` and `material_category`). With `stores` having `material_cat_ids` as a collection and `material_category` table having `material_cat_id` as a number field, I can't us the "in" keyword.

Please suggest the best way to join these tables.

Answer (score 3):

Storing your Material Category ID's as a string is a terrible idea. If it is not too late go back to the drawing board! You are defeating the purpose of a relational database. A better table structure would be a new table Like:

**StoreMaterialCategory**

```
Store_CD (FK Stores), 
Material_Cat_ID (FK Material_Category), 
Primary Key --> (Store_CD, Material_Cat_ID)
```

then get rid of Material_Cat_IDs from stores. I've put an example schema [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4293/3) with a couple of demonstration queries to show how to get 2 of the outputs you may need.

However, if you insist on this table structure then You can do a join like so:

```
SELECT  Store_nm, Name
FROM    Stores
        INNER JOIN material_Category
            ON ',' || material_Cat_ids || ',' LIKE '%,' || CAST(material_Cat_ID AS VARCHAR(5)) || ',%';
```

**[Example On SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a53e/1)**

**EDIT**

If you need the categories in a list you can use:

```
SELECT  Store_nm, 
        LISTAGG(Name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Name) AS Categories
FROM    Stores
        INNER JOIN material_Category
            ON ',' || material_Cat_ids || ',' LIKE '%,' || CAST(material_Cat_ID AS VARCHAR(5)) || ',%'
GROUP BY Store_nm;
```

**[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a53e/10)**

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , i should change my structure it is better for me

Answer (score 2):

```
create table store (store_cd  varchar2(20),store_nm varchar2(20),active  varchar2(1),material_cat_ids varchar2(200));

Insert into STORE
   (STORE_CD, STORE_NM, ACTIVE, MATERIAL_CAT_IDS)
 Values
   ('L', 'Store(L)', 'Y','20,5');
Insert into STORE
  (STORE_CD, STORE_NM, ACTIVE, MATERIAL_CAT_IDS)
 Values
  ('B', 'Store(B)', 'Y', '7');


create table Material_category(material_cat_id number ,name varchar2(20),active varchar2(1));

insert into material_category values(20,' A','Y');
insert into material_category values( 5,' B','Y' );
insert into material_category values(7,'C','Y');

WITH tab as (
SELECT  DISTINCT store_cd
       ,store_NM
       ,active
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR (material_cat_ids, '[^,]+', 1,LEVEL) material_cat_id
FROM store s
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (material_cat_ids, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  ) 
SELECT * from tab t 
             ,material_category mc 
where t.material_cat_id=to_char(mc.material_cat_id);
```

[image: output]

Worked out Example [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c59b4/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
select *
from stores
inner join material_category
on ',' + stores.material_cat_ids + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(100), material_category.material_cat_id) + ',%'
```